# Solve $ T'' + 2aT' - c^2 \lambda T = 0, T'(0) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the following PDE:
$$
u_{tt} + 2au_t - c^2u_{xx} = 0
$$
$$
u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) = 0
$$
$$
u(x,0) = x(\pi-x)
$$
$$
u_{t}(x,0) = 0
$$

Now, i define:
$$
u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)
$$
getting:
$$
\frac{T''+2aT'}{T} = c^2 \frac{X''}{X} 
$$

Therefore:

$$
\frac{X''}{X} = \lambda
$$

$$
\frac{T''+2aT'}{T} = c^2 \lambda
$$

So now i want to solve:

$$
T'' + 2aT' - c^2 \lambda T = 0 
$$
$$
T'(0) = 0
$$

So:

$$
r^2 + 2ar - c^2 \lambda  = 0
$$

Therefore i get:
$$
r_{1,2} = -a \pm i\sqrt{c^2n^2 - a^2}
$$

Therefore we get:
$$
T_n = e^{-at}(A \cos \sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t + B \sin \sqrt{c^2n^2 - a^2}t)
$$

The problem now is that i only have 1 condition: $T'(0) = 0$ but 2 unknowns $A,B$, how can i solve this?

Comment: If you only have one initial value for a second order ODE, you will definitely have one undetermined parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem has gone this long unsolved there must be issues. The first is that we have not been guaranteed that $a<c$, although I think it's safe to assume that $a>0$ because that would correspond to a guitar string clamped at both ends, plucked and released at $t=0$ with viscous damping. So for the modes with $a>cn$ we have
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}\left(A\cosh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t+B\sinh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t\right)$$
For such modes,
$$T_n^{\prime}(0)=-aA+\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}B=0$$
So we can say that
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}\left(\cosh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}}\sinh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t\right)$$
If there is a critically damped mode with $a=cn$ it is
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}(A+Bt)$$
Where
$$T_n^{\prime}(0)=-aA+B=0$$
So that
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}(1+at)$$
For the underdamped modes $a<cn$
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}\left(A\cos\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t+B\sin\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t\right)$$
And in this case
$$T_n^{\prime}(0)=-aA+\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}B=0$$
With solution
$$T_n(t)=e^{-at}\left(\cos\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}}\sin\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t\right)$$
So our solution thus far is
$$\begin{align}u(x,t)&=\sum_{0<n<a/c}b_ne^{-at}\left(\cosh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}}\sinh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t\right)\sin nx\\
&\quad+\sum_{n=a/c}b_ne^{-at}(1+at)\sin nx\\
&\quad+\sum_{n>a/c}b_ne^{-at}\left(\cos\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}}\sin\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t\right)\sin nx\end{align}$$
And now comes the second issue: @EditPiAf seems to have been naughty and changed the initial condition from $u(x,0)=x(\pi-x)$ to $u(x,0)=u(\pi-x)$, which doesn't even make any sense. Thus we claim that the initial condition reads
$$u(x,0)=x(\pi-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin nx$$
And if we integrate
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi}x(\pi-x)\sin mx\,dx&=\left[-\frac{x(\pi-x)}n\cos nx+\frac{\pi-2x}{n^2}\sin nx-\frac2{n^3}\cos nx\right]_0^{\pi}\\
&=\frac{2\left(1-(-1)^n\right)}{n^3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\int_0^{\pi}\sin nx\sin mx\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\frac{\pi}2\delta_{nm}=\frac{\pi}2b_m\end{align}$$
We have our final solution
$$\begin{align}u(x,t)&=\frac4{\pi}e^{-at}\left\{\sum_{0<n<a/c}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\left(\cosh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}}\sinh\sqrt{a^2-c^2n^2}t\right)\sin nx\right.\\
&\quad+\sum_{n=a/c}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}(1+at)\sin nx\\
&\quad+\left.\sum_{n>a/c}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3}\left(\cos\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t+\frac a{\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}}\sin\sqrt{c^2n^2-a^2}t\right)\sin nx\right\}\end{align}$$